# CSS class to append with another class

Tags: css

Is there any way to summarize value of (e.g margin-bottom) between two or more classes?

E.g

> HTML

`<div class="row mrg25B mrg30B"></div>`

> CSS

```
.mrg25B
    margin-bottom: 25px;

.mrg30B
    margin-bottom: 30px;
```

And get a 55px margin bottom.

Comment: You can't do that. The dupe link has 2 suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this specific task by defining a new rule which applies to elements having both classes:

```
.mrg25B.mrg30B {
    margin-bottom: 55px;
}
```

Though it doesn't extend to general case.